# Place each word in a link PHP

Tags: php, string

Let's say I have this block of text in a string:

```
hello guys good man
```

I would like to convert this string (using PHP) to something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q=hello">hello</a> <a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q=guys">guys</a> <a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q=good">good</a> <a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q=man">man</a>
```

Thanks a heck in advance! :)

Would this envolve some regular expressions or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?
$str = "hello guys good man";
$arr = explode(' ', $str);
foreach($arr as $value){
    echo '<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q='.$value.'">'.$value.'</a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Why didn't this envole regex or something? How does explode work? Can you please explain your code? Thanks so much! :D

Comment: [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) requires two parameters. The first tells it to split on a space and the second is the string. Now we have all your words in the array and we simply loop over each word and put it into the link you requested.

Comment: @Sean Sean, I've got one more request, is there anyway to exclude all instances of `<br>` from the array? I don't want `<br>` to be counted a word, or part of a word, and be hyperlinked. Thanks. :)

Comment: 1. Replace `<br>` before explode `$var = str_replace('<br>', ' ', $var);` | 2. Replace multiple spaces with one space `$var = preg_replace('~\s+~', ' ', $var);` | 3. Explode `$var = explode(' ', $var);`

Comment: @Glavić but would his retain the spaces that I had in the original string?

Comment: @SolèneLeVan, have you tried? Second command removes all multiple spaces, which is good practice, if you are exploding by space.

Answer (score -1):

you can just use explode then use foreach.

```
<?php
$a="hello guys good man";
$a=explode(' ',$a);

foreach($a as $linkit)
{
echo '<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q='.$linkit.'">'.$linkit.'</a><br>';
}
?>
```

Hope it helps
Abnab

Comment: It's downvoted because he did exactly what I did. Literally. Just changed a variable name.

Comment: well I posted the answer without refreshing the page. Had not clue someone had posted the answer.well if I had just changed the variable name I wouldn't have added <?php  to <?

Comment: @abnab you could have just changed a variable name and add <?php.

Comment: @SolèneLeVan : NEvermind I will just take -1 for giving the correct answer.

Comment: I +1ed just now to make it better. :)