# Link each word of string WITHOUT linking <br>

Tags: php, string

I'm using a PHP script to link each word of the string:

```
<?
$str = "hello<br> guys good man";
$arr = explode(' ', $str);
foreach($arr as $value){
    echo '<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q='.$value.'">'.$value.'</a>';
}
?>
```

How do I link each word of the string `$str` without linking the `<br>`s?

Comment: Why do you duplicate questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14269595/place-each-word-in-a-link-php I have already answered you in the comment of the correct answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just use `preg_replace`

```
// More complext string
$str = "hello<br> guys good man <a href=\"http://google.com\">Google</a> <br /> hurry";

// Url Template
$template = '<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q=%1$s">%1$s</a>';

// Replace Words
echo preg_replace("/(?!(?:[^<]+>|[^>]+<\/a>))\b([a-z]+)\b/is", sprintf($template, "\\1"), $str);
```

Output

```
<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q=hello">hello</a>
<br>
<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q=guys">guys</a>
<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q=good">good</a>
<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q=man">man</a>
<a href="http://google.com">Google</a>
<br />
<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q=hurry">hurry</a>
```

Comment: Great answer, can you just clarify the need for the `sprintf` related code?

Comment: @DoubleGras I do not want to concatenate the value twice and also its more also old habits die hard see why : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386593/why-use-sprintf-function-in-php

Comment: Gotcha. It's just a bit of modularity, so you can feed the template by a lot of methods without touching it.

Comment: Something like that .... :) see PHP doc for more information http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php

Answer (score 2):

Use the strip_tags() function before/in your explode:

```
$arr = explode (' ', strip_tags($str));
```

Comment: but then how do I retain the `br`s in the echoed result?

Answer (score 2):

Untested, but start with JvO's code and put the links back into the original string:

```
$str = "hello<br> guys good man";
$arr = explode (' ', strip_tags($str));
foreach($arr as $value) {
    $link = '<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q='.$value.'">'.$value.'</a>';
    $str = str_replace($value, $link, $str);
}
echo $str;
```

Note that you can save time by removing duplicates from $arr.

Edit: in fact, you *must* remove duplicates from $arr, or things will get ugly:

```
$arr = array_unique(explode (' ', strip_tags($str)));
```

... and another edit to the original code for an error.

Comment: can you be more specific? What happens?

Comment: just echoes the original. :( without the links ect

Comment: d'oh! $str = str_replace(...)

Comment: no it doesn't work. :( Even when I use arry unique, it's completely messy and disoddard and nothing looks right. :( (Note that I'm dealing with some weird characters in my string, maybe that could be causing it, but i want that fixed), thanks!;)

Comment: Yeah, ultimately I think this approach will be too flakey. If 'search' is in the original string, things will really go haywire. It's possible to work around all that stuff, but if you first create the array with explode(), then hellohellosharp above has a better solution. It will have problems also if there are more complicated tags besides just <br>, but but otherwise seems perfectly fine.  For a more bulletproof solution, preg_match() and preg_replace() are the right tools for the job.

Comment: Yeah, but even hellohellosharps answer was messy a lot of the time... :( So I decided that it was better to just replace the `<br>`s with spaces...

Answer (score 1):

Before you form the link, process the string first:

```
$proc_val = preg_replace('/<br>/', '', $value);
echo '<a href="http://foo.php?q='.$proc_val.'">'.$value.'</a>';
```

Comment: but then how do I retain the `br`s in the echoed result?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you were saying in the comment of Jvo's answer, but you can always use the striptags in the foreach as well and only strip the link part.

```
foreach($arr as $value){
    echo '<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q='.strip_tags($value).'">'.$value.'</a>';
}
```

So here is the full code:

```
<?
$str = "hello<br> guys good man";
$arr = explode(' ', $str);
foreach($arr as $value){
    echo '<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q='.strip_tags($value).'">'.$value.'</a>';
}
?>
```

You really should think about what `explode(' ', $str)` is going to do though.

Any time any HTML tag has attributes to it like `<span style="color: red;">` you are going to run into trouble. You should `strip_tags` *first*, on the entire string, *then* process it. Keep an HTML version as a separate string if you need to add stuff later.

Comment: but then how do I retain the `br`s in the echoed result?

Comment: The first code part of my answer will strip the tags from the URL but keep them in the part that actually displays. Look at this part of it: `searchcompleted.php?q='.strip_tags($value).'">'.$value.'</a>';`

Comment: But it displayed this: Fatal error: Call to undefined function striptags() in /home/content/76/7290476/html/dumbocr/post.php on line 111

Comment: Found the problem, missing an underscore in the striptags function. You might want to edit your original answer. Thanks so much! it works now!

Comment: The resulted text looks ugly, ie linebreaks everywhere inside links, many words linked to the same word ect. :(

Answer (score 1):

Why not just explode the string as you currently are and simply strip the tags in the URL.

```
$str = "hello<br> guys good man";
$arr = explode(' ', $str);
foreach($arr as $value){
    echo '<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q='.strip_tags($value).'">'.$value.'</a>';
}
```

This will output the following HTML which is what I believe you want.

```
<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q=hello">hello<br></a>
<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q=guys">guys</a>
<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q=good">good</a>
<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q=man">man</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the string is quite long, and can contain any number of tags, including `<p>`, `<h1>` and `<br>` as well as the more correct `<br/>`, you could consider parsing the lot, and use `str_replace`:

```
$string = 'Foo<br/>Hello Bar!';
$DOM = new DOMDocument;
//make sure all breaks are preceded by a space, if not words might be concatenated by accident
$DOM->loadHTML(str_replace('<br', ' <br', $string));
//get all nodes
$nodes = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('*');
//get the text, split it and replace, but keep track of replaced words
$replaced = array();
for ($i = 0, $j = $nodes->length; $i<$j;$i++)
{
    $words = explode(' ',$nodes->item($i)->nodeValue);
    while($word = array_shift($words))
    {
        if (!array_key_exists($word, $replaced))
        {//avoid replacing twice (and thus creating a link within a link)
             $replaced[$word] = true;
             $string = str_replace($word, '<a href="http://www.dumbsearch.com/now/searchcompleted.php?q='.urlencode($word).'">'.$word.'</a>', $string);
        }
    }
}
```

This code is tested and working.